# what is the "m" stands for in <m:GetQuotation> in SOAP?

Tags: soap

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

   <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:m = "http://www.example.org/quotations">
      <m:GetQuotation>
         <m:QuotationsName>MiscroSoft</m:QuotationsName>
      </m:GetQuotation>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What is the "m" in ? why it is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is the prefix of the namespace `http://www.example.org/quotations` as defined on the `<Body>` element:

```
xmlns:m = "http://www.example.org/quotations"
```

As part of `<m:GetQuotation>` it moves `<GetQuotation>` into that namespace.

Why would one do that?

Imagine you have a calculation table of furniture tables and you want to define that in XML. There would be `<table>`s all around and there would be no way of distinguishing them. Namespaces help solve that issue and you could declare two namespaces

```
xmlns:xl="Microsoft Excel"
xmlns:f="Furniture"
```

And from now on you could easily distinguish `<xl:table>` from `<f:table>` and it's always clear what you're working on. They would be totally different things.

Applied to your case, it's totally clear that `<m:Quotation>` is a quotation as defined by `http://www.example.org/quotations` and neither one of my personal quotations, nor one of my employer's quotations.